# importing to BigQuery via cron and refresh_and_apply_credential getting 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'apply'

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore

I have a cron job that fetches Datastore dump from Google Storage.

I have tested this Datastore dump by manually importing to BigQuery with these settings:

[image]

and it imports just fine into BigQuery.

My code uses `import googleapiclient.discovery` and it would look something like this:

```
service = googleapiclient.dis covery.build('bigquery', 'v2')

batch = service.new_batch_http_request(callback=insert_bigquery)

# more stuff... 

# and it will fail here
response = batch.execute()
```

And the error from the logs would look something like this:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'apply' at
>   _refresh_and_apply_credentials (/base/data/home/apps/my-app/import-bq.419067140342338621/lib/googleapiclient/http.py:1039)
>   at execute
>   (/base/data/home/apps/my-app/import-bq.419067140342338621/lib/googleapiclient/http.py:1318)
>   at positional_wrapper
>   (/base/data/home/apps/my-app/import-bq.419067140342338621/lib/oauth2client/util.py:142)
>   at get
>   (/base/data/home/apps/my-app/import-bq.419067140342338621/handlers/cron.py:97)
>   at dispatch
>   (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/6a5167f0cae8960d/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py:570)
>   at dispatch
>   (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/6a5167f0cae8960d/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py:572)
>   at dispatch
>   (/base/data/home/apps/my-app/import-bq.419067140342338621/base/handlers.py:224)
>   at dispatch
>   (/base/data/home/apps/my-app/import-bq.419067140342338621/base/handlers.py:297)

Can someone explain what's going on and what things can i try to make this work?

Thank you.

Comment: You're using the older version of the Python SDK. Use the newer one instead and see if it helps: https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-bigquery/. In your code, follow the instructions for loading Datastore objects/backups from GCS here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-datastore

Comment: this is working from another app - is there any chance to make this work using the discovery api or perhaps why do you think it's causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

> You're using the older version of the Python SDK. Use the newer one
>   instead and see if it helps: pypi.org/project/google-cloud-bigquery.
>   In your code, follow the instructions for loading Datastore
>   objects/backups from GCS here:
>   cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-datastore
>
> – Graham Polley

Like Graham said, update the Python SDK, the error is probably due to that. You specify that is already working (even though from another app). I'm not sure what you mean with "make this work using the discovery api", could you clarify?.

Also, on the code you shared there's a space on the line were it builds the discovery client:

```
dis covery.build
```